# How to reclaim memory which used by lots of Strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, garbage-collection

In my project,I found a problem that javascript strings and numbers may take too much non-heap memory.The following code snippet can show the result.

```
let len = 1000000 * 5;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    window['str' + i] = 'helloworld'
}
```

I'm using Google Chrome, and the Task Manager may look like that:
[image]

Here is my question: how can I gc that section of memory? I tried delete the reference by delete syntax or set the reference to null.However neither of them works.So is there a way to triggle GC to that section of memory even though I known the actual storage is not in Heap.

[Reference: Memory Analysis 101](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/memory-analysis-101)

I tooke a Chrome devTool Performance Analysis with the below code:

```
let len = 1000000 * 5;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    window['str' + i] = 20
}

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    window['str' + i] = null
}
```

the result is like that:
[image]
As you can see,I manually triggle GC via devTool button.However the memory still takes too much.[image]

Comment: Assigning the variable to `null` (or to *any* new value) should make the original string available for garbage collection, but you can't *trigger* garbage collection to run immediately. Are you talking about global variables? (I mean, the example shown is creating globals, but does your real code use globals?)

Comment: Maybe `delete window['str' + i]`, but my chrome crashes because that takes too much memory...

Comment: @nnnnnn: I'm not sure scope is relevant here.

Comment: Why do you store them as the global variables in the first place?

Comment: @Cerbrus I think it is, global variables won't be GC'ed as the GC doesn't really know it they're still needed or not, whereas variables scoped to a function or block it will

Comment: you can reduce the len count.And the code above is just for a demo

Comment: @George: even if you `delete` them?

Comment: @Cerbrus - The question does mention trying to set the references to `null`, but I wondered if in the real project there were globals that weren't reassigned.

Comment: Yes.even if I delete them and the memory doesn't reduce.

Comment: Measure the actual memory consumption with memory profiler.

Comment: As the Google Memory Analysis 101 says, the actual content of String and Number may not be stored in Heap.For example, the string may stored in render memory.However my question is how can I clear that section of memory.They took too much memory of my computer.Does anyone know the solution.Thanks ahead.

Comment: why are you storing them on the `window` object? adding those fields to a local object (`{}`, `Object.create(null)`, a `Map` or some custom `class` instance) would be far better and allow you to throw away the object once it's no longer needed.

Comment: "how can I clear that section of memory" --- just remove all references to them. You cannot do anything besides of that.